# Can one future have multiple waiters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

If I create a future and schedule it, is it possible to have two waiters (`asyncio.wait`) waiting on it so when it completes they both eventually wake up and continue? Can both waiters get the result and get any exception raised by the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have any number of tasks wait for a single future, they will all be woken up when the future is done. If an exception has been set it'll be raised for all waiting tasks.